# Javascript > Demultiplex/cache a Promise function call

Tags: javascript, caching, promise, debouncing

**The Problem:**

I'm currently using [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/) (serverside) to handle async requests from a client. These requests are being passed through to an upstream service - which is reasonably expensive/slow and rate limited. I would like to demultiplex/cache calls to the upstream service. **e.g.** 10x calls for `getUserProfile(123)` => 1x call to upstream service (within a time period)

1. I've tried using a cache ([lru-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache)), however a number of calls are received from the client (within milliseconds), before getting a response from the upstream server (for the first call - so that doesn't work).
2. The [debounce-promise](https://github.com/bjoerge/debounce-promise) library sounds like what I need, however it doesn't take into account differing parameters (**e.g.** `getUserProfile(123)` and `getUserProfile(456)` => expecting `profile_123` and `profile_456`, however returns  `profile_456` (twice).

Probably best if I give an example...

**server.js**

```js
// on request from client...
socket.on('getUserProfileRequest', userId => {
    getUserProfile(userId).then(profile => socket.emit('getUserProfileResponse', profile))
})

...

function getUserProfile(userId) {
    // ... call upstream server, do async work, return a Promise...
}
```

Comment: Ad 2.: Have you tried setting `accumulate` to `true` like in [this example](https://github.com/bjoerge/debounce-promise#with-accumulatetrue)? It seems that without this all calls use the same parameter.

Comment: Hi @barbsan - `accumulate` doesn't quite have the functionality I'm trying to capture. I'd like to execute the first request immediately, then cache the result for other invocations using the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `lru-cache` in combination with `maxAge` and `Promises`, to achieve the desired result - I also added an `initialiseFn` parameter to the `get(key, initialiseFn)` function, to facilitate this.

**PR:** https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache/pull/132

```js
// setup an LRU cache (with eviction policy)...
const PROFILE_CACHE = LRU({ max: 50, maxAge: 1000 * 60 })

// receives "lots" of async requests from a client...
socket.on('getUserProfileRequest', userId => {
  PROFILE_CACHE.get(userId, () => getUserProfile(userId))
    .then(profile => socket.emit('getUserProfileResponse', profile))
})

// calls upstream server, does async/expensive/long running work, returns a Promise...
function getUserProfile(userId) { /* ... */ }
```